# Creating related field Domains for ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase, arccatalog, domains

I have been trying to create a new feature class for entering habitat data for ArcGIS Desktop (10.3.1 if relevant). I have been using the coded Domain function to create drop down lists of applicable habitats which can be entered into the shapefile, however I would like to organise this further if anyone has some advice.

As an example, I have four field attributes of Habitat categories which are named 'Hab_Cat1,2,3 and 4'. In 'Hab_Cat1', generalised habitats are listed from A-J with 'A' being 'Woodland & Scrub', 'Hab_Cat2' further classifies the habitat as 'A1 - Woodland', 'Hab_Cat3' specifies that the attribute is 'A1.1 - Broad-leaved Woodland', and 'Hab_Cat4' as 'A1.1.1 - Broad-leaved Woodland - semi-natural'.

As a further means of simplifying my table, I would like to limit the options presented as the data is entered into the feature class. For example, once somebody specifies in Hab_Cat1 that the entry is A-Woodland, I would like to make sure that when they get to Hab_Cat2 that their options are now only limited to 'A' options rather than showing the full range of 'A1 - J3' options and so on.

I believe that this may be achievable through the creation of Subtypes, however as I am new to the use of both Domains and Subtypes I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: Maybe try to follow the ESRI help (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/subtypes/creating-subtypes.htm) then if you encounter problem update your question with what didn't work

Comment: Domains are a feature of geodatabase, not shapefile.

Answer (score -1):

I Don't know if it's relevant for your case- but QGIS has an option of cascading selections. See the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtpUP5n_78E

Comment: This question is about ArcGIS Desktop.